# What do green/brown(orange?)/yellow attribute highlights mean?

Tags: keyframes

Shown here, a green (location (x,y,z)), brown (rotation (x,y,z)) and yellow (scale (x,y,z)) colored attribute highlight. What do these mean? (And where are they documented?)

[image]

Comment: Its always interesting when the question gets near zero votes yet people are clearly voting for answers.  One vote for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These colors all have to do with [Keyframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/index.html).

**Yellow**: Keyframe has been set on current frame

**Green**: No Keyframe on current frame

**Orange**: The property has been changed but a keyframe hasn't been set

I could not find where Blender actually documents these colors though.

Comment: The linked answer from [@Rich Sedman (Thank You Rich)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204029/what-do-green-brown-yellow-attribute-highlights-mean#comment343327_204029) points to this document where the colors are mentioned :) https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/introduction.html#animation-state-colors